# Checked the checkbox if value of each checkbox match string in the c# array string using jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have asp.net mvc 3 application. I have build the EDIT View which consist of different checkbox with same name and different value. I want to checked the checkbox by matching value of checkbox with the value in array of the string of c#.

**Action:**

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    string[] AllRole = roleassign.Role.Split(',');
    ViewBag.allrole = AllRole;
    ViewBag.role = ivr.get_all_role();
    return View();
}
```

AllRole is array String consist of "administrator","member","supervisor"

**View**

```
          @foreach (var list in ViewBag.role)
            {
            <input type="checkbox" name="role" value=@list.Name /> @list.Name
            }
```

How Can I loop through the ViewBag.allrole array string in jquery and checked the checked box which have value that is in the ViewBag.allrole array string.
**Edited**
In View It Creates Entire set of Checkbox of all avaiable Role as follows:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="Administrator" name="role">
Administrator
<input type="checkbox" value="Moderator" name="role">
Moderator
<input type="checkbox" value="voice" name="role">
voiceanchor
<input type="checkbox" value="member" name="role">
member
```

If the ViewBag.allrole consist of array of `"administrator","moderator"` then I want to checked the checkbox with those value in checkbox using jquery

Comment: Where are the roles that are not checked coming from?

Comment: if the role is not in ViewBag.allrole is not checked.

Comment: Ok, let me put it another way, where is the code that creates the checkboxes for the entire set of roles?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using .NET Membership, you can do something like:

```cs
@foreach (var role in Roles.GetAllRoles)
{
    bool checked = Roles.IsUserInRole(role);

    <input 
         type="checkbox"  
         name="role" 
         value="@role.Name" 
         @(checked ? "checked='checked'" : "")/> @role.Name
}
```

in your particular example, you can do almost the same

```cs
string[] userRoles = ViewBag.role;

@foreach (var list in ViewBag.allrole)
{
    bool checked = userRoles.Contains(role);

    <input 
         type="checkbox" 
         name="role" 
         value="@list.Name" 
         @(checked ? "checked='checked'" : "")/> @list.Name
}
```

please change your variables accordingly if I missed something, as they're not very intuitive.

Comment: The second one actually worked. I was so confused as two viewbags created a mess. saved me thanks!. `.Contains()` did a top notch work!!